# Couldn't open png, python pygame, same directory

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I'm writing a game in python using pygame. I have a code:

```
    imageJBird = pygame.image.load("jbirdnapis.png")
```

Everything was working but suddenly it stopped. Now I have an error "Couldn't open jbirdnapis.png". The image is in the same directory as the code. I use Pycharm to execute the game. It works on other contributor's computer - also Ubuntu, the same version. We have the same version from git repository. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide a stack trace?

Comment: Of course
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oleistka/Desktop/projektJBird/J-Bird/jBird/view/states/Intro.py", line 45, in <module>
    intro = Intro()
  File "/home/oleistka/Desktop/projektJBird/J-Bird/jBird/view/states/Intro.py", line 24, in __init__
    imageJBird = pygame.image.load("jbirdnapis.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open jbirdnapis.png

Comment: I believe PyCharm runs the script from the project root directory. Simply use a relative path (with `os.path`) or change the path to the image to step through the project directories.

Comment: Could you add `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to the top of your code and reply with the resulting path?

Comment: @rlee827
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/oleistka/Desktop/projektJBird/J-Bird/jBird/view/states/Intro.py
/home/oleistka/Desktop/projektJBird/J-Bird/jBird/view
and then traceback

Comment: BTW: Polish groups on Facebook: [Python Poland](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpl/) and [Python: pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs script in folder `view`, not in `view/states‌` so it is searching image in `view`.

You can get script's folder and add to all images.

```
import os

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

imageJBird = pygame.image.load(os.paht.join(folder, "jbirdnapis.png"))
```

It will be usefull when you will run in different places.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works but I'm curious why it worked earlier and on other computer. Do you know the answer?

Comment: if you execute from folder `states` as `python script.py` then "current working directory" (CWD) is `states` but you (or PyCharm) can run it from folder `view` as `python states/script.py` and then CWD is `view` and it searchs in this folder. BTW: try in code `print( os.getcwd() )`